# Spring Auto login issue

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm trying to implement the below spring auto login, but my authenticationManager instance throws the below exception and is not autowired.  How do I get an instance of it from Spring manually?  I'm not using a spring controller, I'm using a JSF request scoped bean. I get the below exception at runtime when the container tries to autowire the authenticationManager.  The requestCache comes in fine.  Should I be using a method on my UserDetailsService implementation (userManager)? I don't see an appropriate method exposed by UserDetailsService that takes a UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken objet.  Any ideas?
config:

```
 <http access-denied-page="/auth/denied.html">
        <intercept-url
            pattern="/**/*.xhtml"
            access="ROLE_NONE_GETS_ACCESS" />
        <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/**"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,ROLE_USER" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/auth/*"
            access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
         <intercept-url
            pattern="/registered/*"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
          <intercept-url
            pattern="/*"
           access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <form-login
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check.html"
            login-page="/auth/login.html"
            default-target-url="/registered/home.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.html" />
         <logout invalidate-session="true" 
              logout-success-url="/" 
              logout-url="/auth/logout.html"/>
        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
        <remember-me user-service-ref="userManager" key="e37f4b31-0c45-11dd-bd0b-0800200c9a66"/>
    </http>
    <!-- Configure the authentication provider -->
    <authentication-manager alias="am">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager">
                <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

**Exception**
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager com.dc.web.actions.SignUpDetail.authenticationManager; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] is defined: expected single matching bean but found 2: [org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0, org.springframework.security.authenticationManager]
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)

```
 @Named
```

@Scope("request")
 public class Signup
 {

```
 @Inject
 RequestCache requestCache;

 @Inject
 protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

 public String login(){
authenticateUserAndSetSession(utilities.getLoggedInUser(), (HttpServletRequest)        FacesUtils.getExternalContext().getRequest());
    return "/home.html";
}
 private void authenticateUserAndSetSession(Users user,
            HttpServletRequest request)
        {
     UserDetails details = userManager.loadUserByUsername(user.getUsername());
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernameAndPassword = 
      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
          user.getUsername(), "pwd", details.getAuthorities());

  // Authenticate, just to be sure
  Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(usernameAndPassword);

  // Place the new Authentication object in the security context.
  SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
}
```

Comment: You have two authentication managers according to the exception.  You need to tell the Autowire which one you want to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that Spring Security internally declares the second `AuthenticationManager`, so that you have two of them. You need to choose one of them with `alias`:

```
<authentication-manager alias = "am">
    ...
</authentication-manager>
```

---

```
@Inject @Named("am")
protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
```

Comment: thanks for the help.  I think I just need to associate a role to the user when I auto login, but I'm unsure how to do that.  I still get redirected to my login page (after adding auto login code) when I make a request to /registered/home.html after the SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticatedUser); call.  I added my intercept urls above.  Any ideas?

Comment: @c12: Authentication provider should associate roles to authentication tokens itself, so I don't have any ideas why it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah its weird, the Authentication object says im authenticated and have and my principal is correct

Comment: @c12: Actually, it can be caused by the fact that security context is not saved in the session. Typically, it's caused by `filters=none` on `intercept-url`, but you don't have it. Also `getSession()` looks suspicious.

Comment: I changed my code a bit and don't have the getsession call anymore, but still it doesn't store it in session

Answer (score 1):

@c12 If you are using customized role based authorization it is possible that the internal **authorities** collection of your **UserDetails** is not populated inside of the **loadUserByUsername** method of your **UserManager** class; If that is the case you will require to associate particular roles manually to the **authorities** collection. Check out snippet below (ideally it should be a part of the **loadUserByUsername** method body); It is assumed that...
a) MyUser is your own user object
b) MyUserRole is your own role object
c) userDetails is what you will return from the loadUserByUsername method

```
MyUser myUser = userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
Set<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthSet = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
Set<MyUserRole> myUserRoleSet = myUser.getRoleSet();

for (Iterator<MyUserRole> iterator = myUserRoleSet.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
    MyUserRole userRole = (MyUserRole) iterator.next();
    grantedAuthSet.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getName()));
}

List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(grantedAuthSet);
myUser.setAuthorities(grantedAuthList);
UserDetails userDetails = new User(myUser.getUsername(), myUser.getPassword(), true, true, true, true, myUser.getAuthorities());
```

Hope this helps!